# Уведомления о действиях

Tags: php, javascript

Как реализовать вывод уведомлений на сайте после, к примеру, изменении данных через форму? Допустим, меняю пароль своего аккаунта на сайте и, после отправки данных, PHP страница не тупо молча перезагружается через header();, а показывает уведомление в диалоговом окне JS типа "Пароль успешно изменен." Ищу в инете, не могу найти. Поделитесь ссылкой, если есть, либо опишите примерный алгоритм действий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброго времени суток. Такой интерактив делается таким вот макаром:

Первым делом создаем файлик проверки смены пароля, назовем его **newpass.php**, в нем проверяем введенный новый пароль пользователем:

```
<?php
function newpass($pass){
  /* Тут делаем Ваши проверки все дела и выводим результат*/
  $result = "Вы успешно поменяли пароль";
  return $result;
}

newpass($_POST['newpass']);
?>
```

Что мы сделали? Правильно, создали функцию смены пароля, пароль она будет получать через пост запрос, который сейчас мы сварганим с помощью **jQuery**. Создаем еще один файлик, назовем его **index.html**, в него впихиваем:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
      $.post('newpass.php', {newpass: $('#pass').attr('value')}, function success(data){
        alert(data);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
<body>
  <form name='newpass' id='newpass' method='POST' />
    <input type='pass' name='pass' id='pass' /><br />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Сменить пароль'>
  </form>
</body>
```

Не забываем подключить библиотеку **jQuery**.

В **index.html** мы отправляем пароль в наш обработчик **newpass.php** получаем ответ от обработчика и выводим его на экран без перезагрузки странички. Вот и вся магия.